# Can't open Saleslogix SLX connection

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, iis-8.5, saleslogix

I can't open a SLX connection with a Classic ASP (VBScript) page:

```
Set connSlx = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
connSlx.open "Provider=SLXOLEDB.1;Password=pwd;User ID=uid;Initial Catalog=SLXDB;Data Source=192.168.100.1;PORT=1706;"
```

Error:

> Provider error '80004005'
>   Unspecified error

If I open the SLX connection with an ASPX script and return to my Classic ASP page, the connection is working and I can query the SLX database.

How can I open the SLX connection with Classic ASP ?

Configuration:

- IIS 8.5
- SLX 8
- Oracle 11.2

The ASPX and Classic ASP pages are running in the same Application Pool (Integrated, CLR 4.0, Identity Network Service).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I managed to find the solution:

In IIS, in my site, feature name: IIS/Authentication: Anonymous Authentication, I changed the Application user identity to **Application pool identity**.

Full configuration to make it work:

- Application Pool: Identity->Network Service, Load User Profile->True, Enable 32-Bit Applications: True
- Site: Authentication: Anonymous Authentication->Application pool identity